# SUMIFS returning multiple values in multiple cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs, spill-range

I am running a sumifs function which checks 3 criterias, and must written sum in a single cell. But it automatically returns two more values as 0s in adjacent 2 cells which results in a SPILL! error when I copy the formula and change references respectively.[image]
as per the image I need a sum value based on matching criterias for columns E,F, and G. However, when I am replacing the values for next column, it returns a SPILL. What can be done? I can do it by leaving 2 columns but I know there must be a way out without doing that.

[image]

Comment: Please post the formula as text.  It is hard to read it in the photo.

Comment: If you refer to more criteria it will return a value for each criteria, so don't use E:G, but one of them, or if you intend to sum all three, than wrap the formula in SUM.

Comment: got it, was a silly error, I merged the cells E3:G3, thats why it was returning 3 values. corrected now.

Comment: Careful with using merged cells. I would advice not to use them in data ranges.